# Using of anonymous methods in lock statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

I have to organize thread safe removing of items from collection, with using anonymous method. Something like this.

```
...
lock(this.set)
{
   ...
   this.set.Add(item);

   action(()=>{
      lock(this.set)
      {
         this.set.Remove(item);
      }
   });
}
...
```

Anonymous method will be executed by the time, probably, from another thread. Is this way of lock operators correct? Is there are some riffs i have to take into account here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work however, have you looked at the ConcurrentCollections in .NET 4? They are internally threadsafe

Comment: I have a restriction by .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `action` is doing with the delegate (formed as a lambda expression your case). If it is executing it synchronously then the second `lock` is pointless. Though, it would be safe since a `lock` can be reentered. If it is executing it asynchronously on another thread then you *could* deadlock both threads if `action` waits for any invocation of the delegate to complete. That would be the only the "riff" I can think of.

Comment: I'm not following your train of thought. Can you explain in more detail why this deadlocks?

Comment: Hmm...I was envisioning, perhaps over zealously, a possible implementation of `action` that waited for the delegate to complete. In reading the OP's question again I doubt that would be a likely scenario. Though, even if it were my answer is still misleading. I will probably just delete. Thanks for the "poke" in the right direction on this one.

Comment: I decided to keep the answer, but it has been edited to fix the misleading wording.